# lightswitch computed properties are not searchable

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an entity which has an Id property, and I want to make this property searchable.
I've tried creating a computed property as suggested here:

http://therearefourlightswitches.blogspot.co.nz/2012/02/making-integers-searchable.html

However , the computed property has no "Searchable" checkbox.
Would appricate any help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **string** properties are searchable. Computed properties are **not** searchable.

The only way to do what you want is to add a real string property to the table (as opposed to adding a computed property), then in the entity's *Saving* method, convert the ID to a string & store it the string property. You'll need to do the same for the entity's *Adding* method.

You could use your computed property to set the value of the string property, but that means having two added properties. If you can live with that, it'll make it easier to set the values in both the **Adding** & **Updating** methods, but you could also move the code out of the computed property to a static class/module & call that from the two methods.

EDIT:

Actually the method used by the link you provided isn't using a computed property at all. It's basically what I described. But he suggests using the *Changed* method, which is actually a better approach than what I described above. Using the *Changed* method means you don't have to use both the *Adding* & *Updating* methods, & you won't nmeed two properties either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have computed properties which were imported from 2010 lightswitch with the computed checkbox. was this feature blocked in properties added in LS 2012?

Comment: No, not at all. You can still use computed properties in LS 2012. But computed properties have never been searchable.